# Why are analog signals preferred for high-frequency applications?

Tags: analog, digital-communications, high-frequency

I really don't see what benefit analog signals would give over digital ones in this case.

Comment: Well, analog is smooth like silk, while digital is sharp and hurts.

Comment: For one thing, it is very difficult to generate sharp digital pulses at high frequencies as the required RC time constants for the operation is super low.

Comment: Are they?  Which signals? Which applications?

Comment: The real truth is that there is no such thing as a digital signal.

Comment: Compare, say, a 1GHz bandpass filter made in the analog domain with a digital one.

Comment: Any signal which is about high frequency is a analog signal. So your answer is also the answer..

Answer (score 2):

Via Fourier, digital signals are square waves and so have inherently higher bandwidth than an analog signal, all other things being equal. Intuitively, this is due to all the sharp vertical edges in a digital signal. Sharp vertical edges needs to transition fast and to transition fast requires high frequency components in your signal spectra well beyond the fundamental frequency of the signal (i.e. a pure 100MHz sine wave has a signal spectra from 0Hz to 100MHz while a bipolar 100MHz 5-% duty square wave with perfectly vertical edges has a signal spectra from 0Hz to \$\infty\$ Hz.)

That means that for the same bandwidth, an analog signal can theoretically carry more information than an digital signal. Handling extremely large bandwidth signals is not easy.

Intuitively, analog signals have a higher data density than digital signals because digital signal has been chosen chosen to only represent a finite, often very small, number of data states. But since all real world signals are actually analog, what you have really done is mapped an infinite (if no noise) or near-infinite (with noise) number of analog values to a finite number of digital values. Digital is really more of a way that you have chosen to *interpret* a real world signal (which is always analog). So obviously the data density is going to be less. But doing this makes makes the hardware and processing simpler and more versatile, and makes the signal more immune to noise which also makes storage easier.

Analog is like using your voice to speak words. Digital is like using your voice to yell out Morse code. The speed advantage is obvious.

Answer (score 2):

Digital signals are useful models but are ideal concepts and don't exist in physical form.

So if you think about logic gates, truth tables, and digital waveforms on paper, it is similar to thinking squares, triangles and circles in a math class, because they are ideal models, and you can't construct an ideal square, triangle or circle using physical matter, while you can make good approximations.

So inherently, all ideal digital signals are represented with analog signals, and the signals have to travel through gates that are made of analog components and through a medium that is also capable of passing only analog signals. It does not matter if the medium is wires, optical fibre or radio waves.

With an analogue waveform with certain bandwidth, you can transfer multiple ideal digital bits using a single analog symbol.